# DataBinding issue with DataGrid and DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I guess it's a simple Data Binding issue but I can't make it work. I have a DataGrid, a ViewModel with an Observable Collection and a class that represents objects in this collection. The DataGrid has two columns: A DataGridTextColumn and a DataGridTemplateColumn.
The binding of the data with the DataGridTextColumn works but the binding with the DataGridTemplateColumn doesn't. The corresponding column simply remains empty.

Here is the code:

This is my DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="tdg_Memory" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0" Grid.Row="4" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="MemoryIndexColumn" Header="Index"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="MemorySolutionColumn" CellTemplate="{DynamicResource MemorySolutionCellTemplate}" Header="Solution"/>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGrid>
```

This is the DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MemorySolutionCellTemplate">
    <Grid x:Name="grd_RootGrid" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label x:Name="lbl_ValueCaption" Content="Value:" Margin="0" Grid.Row="0" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        <Label x:Name="lbl_FitnessCaption" Content="Fitness:" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label x:Name="lbl_ValueValue" Content="65665" Grid.Column="1" Height="Auto" Margin="12,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <Label x:Name="lbl_FitnessValue" Content="121212" Grid.Column="1" Margin="12,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The data binding occurs in code behind:

```
// setting the itemsSource (seems to work)
jobItem.tdg_Memory.ItemsSource = jobModel.Memory;

// binding of the first column (DataGridTextColumn) seems to work
Binding memoryIndexColumnBinding = new Binding();
memoryIndexColumnBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Index");
jobItem.MemoryIndexColumn.Binding = memoryIndexColumnBinding;
```

And here is the ViewModel:

```
// the observable collection that holds the data for the DataGrid
private ThreadSafeObservableCollection<MemoryItemRepresentative> _memory;

    public ThreadSafeObservableCollection<MemoryItemRepresentative> Memory {
        get { return _memory; }
        set {
            _memory = value;

            FirePropertyChanged("Memory");
        }
    }
```

Here are the objects included in the collection:

```
public class MemoryItemRepresentative : ViewModelBase {

        private int _index;

        public int Index {
            get { return _index; }
            set {
                _index = value;

                FirePropertyChanged("Index");
            }
        }

        private MPBILSolution _solution;

        public MPBILSolution Solution {
            get { return _solution; }
            set {
                _solution = value;

                FirePropertyChanged("Solution");
            }
        }

        public MPBILPropabilityVector PropabilityVector;

        public MemoryItemRepresentative () {

        }
    }
```

And the MBILSolution is (but that should be irrelevant for that problem):

```
public class MPBILSolution : ISolution {

    public int Position { get; set; }
    public BinaryNumber Value { get; set; }
    public double Fitness { get; set; }

}
```

What I want to do now is to have the DataGrid first column (the DataGridTextColumn) be bound to the Index property of the MemoryItemRepresentative class which works fine.

Furthermore I want to display the contents of the MPBILSolution object (consisting of Properties Position, Value and Fitness) be bound to the second column (the DataGridTemplateColumn). For that reason I have built the DataTemplate that comprise a label for the Value property and a label for the Fitness property.

I have not posted the actual binding code which is not working because my problem seems to be that the corresponding column of the DataGrid always remains empty. At least the static labels inside the DataTemplate (which are used for captioning) should be visible ?

So I am very thankful for any help.
Any further code on request ...

**Appendix:**

Well now the actual binding seems to make problems: In the DataGrid I can now see the DataTemplate inside the column but the values of the MPBILSolution object are missing:

Here is how I do the binding of this object to the DataTemplate:

```
DataTemplate memorySolutionCellTemplate = (DataTemplate)jobItem.FindResource("MemorySolutionCellTemplate");

        DependencyObject o = memorySolutionCellTemplate.LoadContent();

        Label l = (Label)VisualTreeAssistant.FindFrameworkElement(o, "lbl_FitnessValue");


        Binding fitnessValueBinding = new Binding();
        fitnessValueBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Fitness");
        fitnessValueBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
        l.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, fitnessValueBinding);
```

The object l seems to get the correct Label object so the problem seems to lie in the last four lines of this binding block ?

Please help again :)

Comment: Why `DynamicResource`? If you can use `StaticResource` do so, `DynamicResource` can be quiet about errors i think (possibly check the Output window)...

Comment: @H.B. SOLVED! You did solve it ! Post your comment as answer and I will explain what happened :)

Comment: Show me your moves then!

Comment: @H.B. Are you still there ? Maybe you can help me again ? Now the actual binding of the MPBILSolution object to the DataTemplate makes problems: During runtime I now see the DataTemplate but not the values that should be bound to the lables.. Maybe you can have a look to it again ?

Comment: You cannot modify a DataTemplate at runtime, what you do there is you create one instance from the template and modify that, not going to affect anything. You need to create the full template either statically or dynamically. (Also don't use labels for values, read the documentation, Labels provide certain functionality (access keys) and are not meant for this)

Comment: @H.B. I am creating the DataTemplate inside the UserControl which I've named `jobItem` (see above). So you mean although I am creating a new instance of that UserControl (also including a new DataTemplate since the DataTemplate gets instantiated in the UserControl's XAML) and refering to the label of this particular DataTemplate (with `FindResource(...)` the error lies here ? I mean with that I am creating the DataTemplate dynamically - or am I completely wrong ?

Comment: The problem is not the instance of the `DataTemplate` but the instance of the controls described by the `DataTemplate` which you create via `LoadContent`, any changes to this instance derived from the `DataTemplate` do **not** affect the `DataTemplate` (the description) itself. As i said, you cannot modify the desciption, people tried and failed. You can create the full template XAML in code and then parse it to a `DataTemplate` using [`XamlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx).

Comment: @H.B. OK I think I got your point. In the meantime I made it work with the following approach: I did not change anything but instead of doing the binding in code I simply added `Content="{Binding Solution.Fitness}"` to the corresponding Label inside the DataTemplate in my UserControls XAML of course without having a data source attached to it because it is what comes during runtime. (Surprisingly the XAML compiles). Then during runtime I am simply attaching my (dynamically created) model to the UserControls DataContext and it works fine.Nevertheless I won't bother you any longer :) THANK YOU !

Comment: There is nothing surprising about that, firstly all bindings are a runtime thing, secondly DataTemplate are just *descriptions*, no actual binding takes place until a control uses the template to create controls from it  (which may or may not contain bindings). Also as i said don't use Labels for the values, use TextBlocks.

Comment: @H.B. Well of course I forgot to mention one change I made in order to make it work: Like you suggested I created a separate class to represent my MPBILSolution and let it implement the INPC. `So, now I am out :)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why `DynamicResource`? If you can use `StaticResource` do so, `DynamicResource` can be quiet about errors i think (possibly check the Output window)...

Comment: The code line that includes the reference to the DataTemplate which is `<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="MemorySolutionColumn" CellTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate3}" Header="Solution"/>` was generated by Blend (as the rest of the XAML code). I even didn't notice that Blend here used a `DynamicResource`. After your comment I changed `DynamicResource` into `StaticResource` and now it's working like a charm. I am wondering why Blend here uses `DynamicResources` - Do you have any idea ? And of course thank you very much for your rescuing comment :)

Comment: @Marc: No idea, Blend works and fails in mysterious ways :P I think the more interesting question is why `DynamicResource` does *not* work here...

Comment: @H.B. The reason I think is that the column is not a child of the grid in the xaml tree so dynamic resource cannot find a local resource. The static resource must be evaluated differently at compile time I suspect.

Comment: @MikeKulls: That makes sense, DynamicResource is similar to bindings and bindings in those columns will fail as well.

Comment: @H.B. What do you mean that bindings will fail? Usually binding will work. With bindings it will use the Context which can be what you expect but with DynamicResource it must use the xaml tree to search for the resource. This is not just limited to the case of the grid, in some cases the object looks like it is a child of something but it is actually the child of something else.

Comment: @MikeKulls: No, in such a context bindings will fail. DataContext bindings will fail because there is none, ElementName does not work because the namescope is cut off and RelativeSource obviously won't work either as the objects are not connected to any tree.

Comment: @H.B. Ah, I see what you mean. I usually just put any binding inside the template for the DataGridTemplateColumn. Then the context is the data for the row. What I presume you are talking about is binding properties of the column, eg Header={Binding SomeProperty}?